# How do I link to a static library (libtiff) using CMake in my wxWidgets project?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, static-libraries, wxwidgets

For my wxWidgets project, I am trying to make the switch from my self-written Makefile to Cmake. I develop on macOS.

When I was writing that Makefile I ran into an issue with libtiff. I wanted to statically link my application so that I don't have to distribute any dylibs myself or rely on my users to install them. I built wxWidgets as a static library but when I compiled my code and checked my binary with `otool` I always found that my binary required a local dylib.

```
/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
```

Finally I found a solution [on here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Distributing_WxWidgets_Applications-Distributing_WxMac_Programs). In essence, in the linking line of my Makefile I replaced `wx-config –-libs` with `LDFLAGS`. `LDFLAGS` looks like this:

```
WXCONFIGLIBS := $(shell wx-config --libs)
WXCONFIGLIBS := $(WXCONFIGLIBS:-ltiff=/usr/local/opt/libtiff//lib/libtiff.a)
# I am not sure whether the double slash is a typo but it works so I don't change it
LDFLAGS := $(WXCONFIGLIBS)
```

Basically, I search-and-replaced `-ltiff` with the path to my static libtiff library.

Now I've managed to compile my project using Cmake. However, I'm getting the same warning message as I did when I battled my original issue.

```
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/lib/libtiff.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.11)
```

How do I fix this? My CMakeLists contains these sections pertaining to wxWidgets:

```
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
...
add_executable(myapp ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(myapp ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
set_property(TARGET myapp PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

I already tried running some search-and-replace shenanigans like

```
string(REPLACE "-ltiff" "/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.a" wxWidgets_LIBRARIES ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

But that doesn't work. It does replace `-ltiff` but also seems to remove the semicolons and whitespaces separating the different libraries.

I've been scouring the web for any clues as to what to do, but I don't seem to have a good enough grasp of libraries to fix this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Within `string(REPLACE)` invocation wrap the source into **double quotes**: `string(REPLACE "-ltiff" "/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.a" wxWidgets_LIBRARIES "${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}")`. So semicolons won't be corrupted.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I can't believe that the solution was this simple and I can't believe that I was sitting on the correct answer for hours. Many thanks!

Comment: On Stack Overflow we do not mix **problems** and **solutions**. So, a question post should contain only problem, a solutions should be posted as answers. On Stack Overflow you may answer your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Please, do that, and move `EDIT (Solution)` part into your answer.

Comment: @chiasmos, since you are on OSX, 2 questions. 1. Are you building an Application Bundle? If not - you should? 2. Do you know that with Application Bundle you should place all your dylib inside and therefore do not distribute them separately? And so you can successfully build wxWidgets official (as dynamic linking) way.

Comment: @Igor I am distributing my app as app bundle. However, I want the app to have some backwards compatibility with regard to macOS version. If I remember correctly, I ran into issues when I distributed the dylib to older macOS versions if the dylib was built for newer versions.

Comment: @chiasmos, in order for wxWidgets library to be fully compatible, you should use `--with-osx-version-min`configure option. Keep in mind though, that current master IIRC should be built with 10.10 or above. If you don't provide this option, the build will use the current OSX version as minimal.

Comment: @Igor I've used this flag: `--with-macosx-version-min=10.11`. Despite this I'm getting the warning `dylib was built for newer macOS version than being linked`. I think it's because libtiff is a third party library.

Comment: @chiasmos, do you see the same warning when building/running `drawing` sample?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My search-and-replace idea turned out to be not so bad. I was able to achieve the same outcome with Cmake as with my Makefile.

My problem was not using double quotes in the appropriate place. So instead of this:

```
string(REPLACE "-ltiff" "/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.a" wxWidgets_LIBRARIES ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

I simply needed to write:

```
string(REPLACE "-ltiff" "/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.a" wxWidgets_LIBRARIES "${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}")
```

So to solve my actual problem, I am calling this `string()` command just before the `target_link_libraries()` command.

Answer (score 0):

Set `wxWidgets_USE_STATIC=ON` before calling `find_package(wxWidgets)`. See the documentation for `wxWidgets` here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindwxWidgets.html

```
option(wxWidgets_USE_STATIC "Link to wxWidgets statically" ON)

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
...
add_executable(myapp ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_features(myapp PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

Comment: I confirmed with `otool` that this doesn't work. If I understand correctly, this option just specifies which wxWidgets build the compiler should use if there is more than one installed. I only every built wxWidgets statically, so that doesn't make a difference.